# Run tox without creating virtual environment

Tags: python, tox

I have tox installed in /etc/bin/tox and I want to test my project with py37 env. I have all dependencies available globally so I don't really need to create virtual environment. But when I execute /etc/bin/tox -e py37 -v I get no module named virtualenv (I cannot install virtualenv)

Is it possible to run tox with without creating virtual environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tox doesn't allow you to do this out of the box, but it's possible such functionality by using https://pypi.org/project/tox-current-env plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://pypi.org/project/tox-direct/ by my friend Oliver Bestwalter.

Comment: That package is deprecated and not recommended.